# I want use && operator and Not operator at the same time in IF statement

Tags: php, if-statement, and-operator, not-operator

I want use && operator and Not operator at the same time in IF statement. If it is possible then how to write it. Below is the statement which i have written is it right?

```
if(!$row['sl_name'] && !$row['sn_name']){
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with the way you have written it?

Comment: What is it not supposed to be? Or do you mean `if(!isset())`

Comment: @Andreas : I am searching those value in database is it there or not if it is not then i can insert the variable

Comment: @Yash : I haven't tried it will be trying in sometime and will let you know is it  right or wrong

Comment: _"I haven't tried it will be trying in sometime"_ - Really? You're writing code and ask us to validate it for you before you even _tried_ it? Trying your own code before posting is definitely a _minimum requirement_.

Answer (score 1):

You can write like this if you wish to check for blank variables:

```
if(!empty($row['sl_name']) && !empty($row['sn_name'])){

}
else{
}
```

It checks for both the variables are not empty if anyone of them is empty it goes to else part.

Comment: Honestly, since the OP haven't even tried the original code in the question, I don't think this post deserves any answers. It should be closed for lack of debug info...

Comment: i agree with you brother.